# How do I do a RegExp replace inside a jQuery template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

Suppose I have

```
{ price: '$ 9.99 USD' }
```

and in my jQuery template I want to do this

```
{{html String(price).replace(/([^A-Z ]+)/gi, '<em>$1</em>')}}
```

Check out this fiddle and notice the change in output that adding/removing the `$1` makes: http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/KNAtz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `$&` what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/KNAtz/5/

Comment: Thanks.  Any ideas what to do if I need two replacements?  I still can't understand why the jQuery template is crashing.

Comment: Run `replace` multiple times.